# "The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application" - only it isn't true

Tags: ssis, odbc

Truly baffled. Using BIDS/SSIS in SQL 2012 with an ADO .net ODBC connection to a UniVerse 11.2 data source. Have been doing so successfully for years. Now I create a new project on the same machine, create an ADO .net connection using the exact same DSN I am using successfully in another project, and it fails validation. I can read table metadata, I can preview the first 200 rows, but when I actually try to run the package in BIDS I receive an architecture mismatch error on the ADO .net connection almost immediately. I am only using 32 bit drivers/DSNs (I do know the difference between the 64bit and 32ODBC Administration). As stated the exact same type of  ADO .net ODBC connection pointing to the exact same ODBC DSN works flawlessly on the exact same machine in a different project. I have been comparing property sheets and see no differences. I have to be missing something obvious, but I have no idea what that would be.

Answer (score 2):

OK. It turned out to be something exceptionally simple that I probably already figured out 3 years ago and forgot about. There is a Run64bitRuntime property at the Project level in BIDS that defaulted to TRUE. Set it to false and I am off to the races.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was the SQL Agent Jobs' configuration which caused the issue. In the job step properties dialog: General > Advanced tab there is a checkbox labelled "32-bit runtime". The job ran successfully once that was checked.

[image: Checking this box runs the agent job in 32-bit runtime]